# How to identify why IIS is not able to read the web.config?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, web-hosting

I'm trying to get a basic .NET 5.0 app running on a new dev server and it is giving me an error trying to read the `web.config` with no Config Error.

[image]

The hosting framework is installed

[image]

And the App Pool user and folder path are the defaults.

[image]

I even ran Process Monitor and the file is successfully read, so it's the content that is giving it a hard time. This is the `web.config` content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\TestApp.Web.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

The environment variable has been set as well

[image]

There are also no errors in the Event Viewer.

Thoughts?

--- EDIT ---

The file shows the IIS user as having access

[image]

Comment: File permissions? Are you sure the config file is valid? I have seen that error when the config file contains errors.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html You'd better run a report to rule out common issues first.

Comment: The file is being read because Process Monitor said so, and the content is actually 100% generated by Visual Studio. Also the file security shows the IIS user as able to read the file

Comment: @LexLi It reports that the ASP.NET module is not installed as part of IIS, but I clearly installed the hosting package. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with a repair install of the Hosting framework install

Comment: The magic of Windows is that files can be missing for unknown reasons. Thus, a live report on what files are needed and whether they exist can always be helpful :) Glad to see that Jexus Manager helps one more developer.